# Magento2 : Product price coming same for all products

Tags: product-list, product-view, magento-2.1.8

I have created custom block for home page products which is extend from

`Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` block.

After that I have called `$block->getProductPrice($_product);` but it return same price (which is my first product price) for all products.

Comment: Can you post the code where you use that function?

Comment: I'm not sure but its like a cache issue

Comment: Most likely the way you implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I found solution 
use**

```
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
```

**instead**

```
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
```